# document.getElementById is not obtaining the value of input type=text

Tags: javascript, inputtext

In this stripped down VF page, I have 2 standard inputs. I'm trying to get the value of the "testme" input from JS, but the 2nd alert never shows.

Am I missing something?

**VisualForce:**

```html
<apex:page id="t1" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SetLaunchD() {
            alert('ddate is...');
            var ddate = document.getElementById('testme').val();
            alert(ddate);
        }
    </script>
    <apex:form>
        test input <input type="text" id="testme" />
        random input box <input type="Text" id="d2" value=""
                                size="10" onblur="SetLaunchD();"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `var ddate = document.getElementById('testme').value;` instead as `val()` is a jquery-function and not available in native javascript.